# AVAudioSession set category to playback without options fail to Play on AirPods, also set category without options will not apply media info

Tags: ios, swift

AVAudioSession set category to playback without options fail to Play on AirPods:

ex: **This will play on AirPods but not Show Media info on Lock Screen**

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
       AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
       options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker
)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Also set category without options will not apply media info:

ex: **This will not  play on AirPods but Show Media info on Lock Screen**

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing `.defaultToSpeaker` is very strange if you want it to play to AirPods. That said, it doesn't actually matter, since `.defaultToSpeaker` doesn't impact `.playback` at all. [It is only intended to be used with `.playAndRecord`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616462-defaulttospeaker) When using it with unsupported modes, you may find it has unusual behaviors. (`.defaultToSpeaker` doesn't mean "play on the phone speaker." It turns on a variety of routing behaviors that you are likely not expecting.)

The actual issue here is that you haven't allowed A2DP, which is what you want for AirPods. For that, the option is [.allowBluetoothA2DP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771735-allowbluetootha2dp).

A2DP is a high-quality unidirectional protocol, so you can only use it for playing audio, not when you're also trying to record audio (but that seems to be what you're doing here).

AVAudioSession options are fairly complex and subtle. They are not obvious at all, and the names in some cases are even misleading. You should not try to guess which ones to use, or copy example code without understanding what it is doing. You need to read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession) for this.